# Displaying a running total on my website?

Tags: php

I'm having a little trouble working out how to display a running total of sales that have gone through my website.  I have no problem working out how to do this with a single output from one table, but unfortunately for my website the results of total sales are spread across 2 tables in the database.

I normally get the total sales manually using a Union query in SQL (whenever I feel like checking it).  I am trying to devise a means of displaying the total figure on my website as a single number formatted with comma's for thousands.

So far I have managed to create some code which displays the total's from each table as a separate figure.  Apart from the 2 separate figures, this is perfect.  All I need to do is join up the 2 rows of output into a single figure.  The code I currently have is below:

```
$sql= "SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_A` 
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_B`";
$res= mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($res)>0) {
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
echo '<h3>'.number_format($row["total_price"], 0).'</h3>';
  };
};
echo mysql_error();
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle, or SQL Server?

Comment: The first answer to this question from cletus (using the variant PHP code) worked perfectly.  Unfortunately I do not have the correct amount of reputation to add a vote to his answer, but this is the answer that solved my problem.  Thanks for the prompt reply - Bunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them up:

```
$sql = <<<END
SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_A` 
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_B'
END;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$res) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . ' in query ' . $sql);
}
$total = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $total += $row[0];
}
$total = number_format($total, 0);
echo '<h3>Total Sales are $' . $total . '</h3>';
```

Alternatively, it can be done in one query:

```
SELECT SUM(total_price) FROM (
  SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_A` 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_B'
)
```

Personally I'd just add it in code but either works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM
(SELECT price FROM table_A
 UNION
 SELECT price FROM table_B
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only thing you have left to do is take the sum of these values.

```
 $sum = 0;
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
     $sum += $row["total_price"]
 };
 echo '<h3>'.number_format($sum, 0).'</h3>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a single figure as the sum of the values from both tables.

```
   SELECT 
    (SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_A`) +
        (SELECT sum(price) AS total_price FROM `table_B`);
```

Well maybe, you get the idea.